# Wrong TCP checksum calculation by Scapy

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

After asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222184/scapy-tcp-checksum-recalculation-odd-behaviour),  I just wanted to make a simple test. I captured a traffic using `tcpdump`. Filtered out a TCP ACK packet in `Wireshark` and exported the filtered packet to `sample.pcap`.

Now this is pretty much my code for TCP checksum recalculation:

```
from scapy.all import *

ack_pkt = sniff(offline="sample.pcap", count=1)[0]
print "Original:\t", ack_pkt[TCP].chksum

del ack_pkt[TCP].chksum
print "Deleted:\t", ack_pkt[TCP].chksum

ack_pkt[TCP]=ack_pkt[TCP].__class__(str(ack_pkt[TCP]))
print "Recalculated:\t", ack_pkt[TCP].chksum
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Original:   30805
Deleted:    None
Recalculated:   55452
```

Is the checksum recalculation process is correct or is there something else to recalculate the checksum? Since scapy is being used widely for a long time, I guess, there is something wrong in my checksum recalculation.

**Updated with packet information:** (Ethernet header is not shown for a better view.)

To view the packet in hex string:

```
from binascii import hexlify as hex2
ack_pkt = sniff(offline="sample.pcap", count=1)[0]
print ack_pkt.chksum, ack_pkt[TCP].chksum
print hex2(str(ack_pkt[IP]))

del ack_pkt.chksum
del ack_pkt[TCP].chksum
print ack_pkt.chksum, ack_pkt[TCP].chksum
print hex2(str(ack_pkt[IP]))

ack_pkt=ack_pkt.__class__(str(ack_pkt))
print ack_pkt.chksum, ack_pkt[TCP].chksum
print hex2(str(ack_pkt[IP]))

ack_pkt[TCP].chksum=0
print hex2(str(ack_pkt[IP]))
```

And the output I get is:

```
26317 30805
450000345bc840004006*66cd*0e8b864067297c3a0016a2b9f11ddc3fe61e9a8d801000f7*7855*00000101080a47e8a8af0b323857
None None
450000345bc840004006*66cd*0e8b864067297c3a0016a2b9f11ddc3fe61e9a8d801000f7*d89c*00000101080a47e8a8af0b323857
26317 55452
450000345bc840004006*66cd*0e8b864067297c3a0016a2b9f11ddc3fe61e9a8d801000f7*d89c*00000101080a47e8a8af0b323857
450000345bc840004006*66cd*0e8b864067297c3a0016a2b9f11ddc3fe61e9a8d801000f7*0000*00000101080a47e8a8af0b323857
```

(* is only for marking the checksum bytes.)

Isn't it strange? After deleting the checksum, when I put a `ack_pkt.show()`, I see both checksum fields are `None`. But while converting to hex-string, is it been recalculated?

`ack_pkt[TCP].chksum=0` with this, the recalculated checksum comes `0` only.

**Note:**

I've tried with `ack_pkt[TCP].show2()` and I'm getting the same value as I'm getting above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a manual checksum recalculation both with `python` and `C (with libpcap)` by following `one's compliment of one's compliment sum` and I'm getting the same value as `scapy` gets for the mentioned packet. So I guess the checksum calculation in linux-kernel is modified somehow.

(It's better to say one guy is wrong rather than saying all other 3 were wrong. :P)

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you try to copy a complete packet, not just its TCP part:

```
ack_pkt=ack_pkt.__class__(str(ack_pkt))
```

2) Did you try the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665844/comparing-tcp-checksums-with-scapy?rq=1) approach, explicitly converting the packet to a string and recreating it using the string?

3) If none of the above works, please post the TCP ACK packet you are working with

Comment: `1)` Initially I was doing the same only. There I got wrong value. So out of curiosity I tried like as mentioned. `2)` Yes. That also gives the same value only. `3)` I'll update the packet soon. mean while let me try a manual checksum calculation.

Comment: Updated the question with the packet info.